# I have a list (CSV) of some nos. which are same as some zip filenames. I only want to unzip those particular zip files

Tags: python, linux, bash, zip

For example I have a list (CSV file) like:

```
Number
291
292
342
124
345
299
...
```

All .zip files are actually in a google cloud storage - bucket
I will have to copy them to the VM instance in a directory
My directory will have more than 1000 .zip files like:

```
101.zip, 102,zip,...199.zip,
201.zip, 202.zip,...299.zip,
301.zip, 302.zip,...399.zip, etc
```

I only want to unzip the files which are in the CSV file using either shell script or python. How can I do that?

Comment: Please include what you have attempted so far and how is it not working.

Comment: If you want to pass you gotta go to class. Don't skip and then dump homework problems here. You are expected to make an effort. Also see [How do I ask homework questions on Stack Overflow](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+do+I+ask+homework+questions+on+Stack+Overflow).

Answer (score 0):

You need to read file line by line like:

```
while read -r line; do
    echo "read line is $line"
done < file.csv
```

for each line extract zip file...